# Oracle on lxc in ubuntu

Tags: linux, oracle11g, linux-containers

I'm currently trying to install an oracle server (11g) in a linux container on ubuntu (following this tutorial (*http://www2.hawaii.edu/~lipyeow/ics321/2014fall/installoracle11g.html*).

When I try to change the file handler with sysctl, the modifications doesn't save into my container. Moreover, when I make the modification in the main ubuntu kernel, it propagates to the containers, so my question is as follow:

- How can I modify the file handlers only in my oracle container ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the Orabuntu-LXC project code.  It supports Ubuntu 16.04, 17.04, 17.10 and is purpose-built for running Any Oracle on Any Linux, including Ubuntu Linux. Note that as you probably already know, Oracle Corp does not formally support or certify Oracle on Ubuntu Linux.

As far as you question about the file handlers, some sysctl values can only be set at the LXC host level, and some can be set in the container.

https://sites.google.com/site/nandydandyoracle/oracle-rac-in-lxc-linux-containers/oracle-lxc-vlc#TOC-Install-the-etc-sysctl.conf-File-Required-for-Oracle

https://github.com/gstanden/orabuntu-lxc

https://sites.google.com/site/nandydandyoracle/

Please note that the step-by-step guides are quite old and that the basic LXC infrastructure together with OpenvSwitch, an LXC-containerized DNS/DHCP, and an optional SCST Linux SAN can all be installed on Ubuntu 16.04, 17.04 and 17.10 with one command:

./anylinux-services.sh

after completion of which all you would need do is download your Oracle database installtion media and install.